# User not logged in even after Fed Auth shows it's expiration in year 2015

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, authentication, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

I have an issue regarding the cookies. I have set all 3 FormsTokenLifetime, WindowsTokenLifetime and ServiceTokenLifetime to 365 days and the cookie is persistent. When any user login to the site he/she is showed to be as logged in user. Now he/she closes their browser and open it after a day or 2 and try to browse the site then it shows that it's not logged in. But we can see that the FedAuth cookie is there till 2015 in the browser.

Please let me know if there is any another setting also for the same OR I am doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey i think it might have to do with some browser settings check out this link http://blog.repsaj.nl/index.php/2011/12/sharepoint-2010-changing-the-cookie-expiration-for-forms-authentication/

Comment: @spStacker thanks for your reply.. But I have a query. Is it necessary to change all 3 properties to the same days?? I have already done this but just now I figured out that `ServiceTokenLifetime` is set to 10 hours. but the `FormsTokenLifetime` and `WindowsTokenLifetime` is set to 365 days.

Comment: i am not sure about it :(